# DSP applications in OCR

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing, ocr

I am doing an assignment about DSP. I want to apply DSP to OCR. I searched around the internet but found not much. Please give me some keywork or document about this. I don't know how to convert an image file into digital signals. I know that images are stored as digital data. But I don't know the connection between a file in computer and what I learnt in DSP (signal, transform, filter, ...).

Comment: You know an image is essentially a discrete 2D signal, right?  What you know about 1D filters in DSP can easily be applied to 2D.  One possible way is to consider each row of pixels as a separate 1D signal.  Depending on what you're doing, this is a good approach and reduces complexity. What exactly do you want to do with OCR?

Comment: I want to recognize a short text by OCR. I am searching the DSP algorithm, understand it and implement it as code. I found a ORC matlab here: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18169-optical-character-recognition--ocr-) but I didn't found DSP around that code (maybe it has but i didn't realize). I want to see DSP applied in code.

Comment: Any kind of image processing will inevitably involve some "DSP" algorithms.  As such, I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.  What you're seeing in the code is mostly morphological image processing.  If you want *specific* DSP algorithms (like averaging, low pass filter, high pass filter, etc.) that is mostly used in **pre-processing** the data.  *Recognizing* the actual characters is a machine learning problem.

Comment: Actually, I am learning DSP. For now, I just know about input signals, discrete-system, output-signals and calculate difference equations of them. I have to do an assigment and I want to do about OCR. As I said, for now, I know nothing about this. So I study to do it. I want some keyworks or documents to research. That's my question. If you know how to do it, please tell me what to study step by step, that' great.

Comment: Recognizing the actual text itself unfortunately requires no DSP to do it. That is a machine learning / classification problem.  What I can suggest is you looking up how to clean up noisy text images or enhancing the contrast *so that the classification can be better*.  Here you can take a look at any contrast enhancement techniques: Unsharp Masking, High-Boost Emphasis Filtering, Gamma Correction, etc. You'll learn those difference equations for LPF, HPF and all that much later.... (continued on my next comment).

Comment: What I'd recommend for you to get started in the image domain is take a look at Richard Alan Peters website: https://archive.org/details/Lectures_on_Image_Processing - Look at the filtering methods specifically.  It's basically taking DSP and going into the 2D domain.  You can artificially corrupt text images with noise, try to clean it up using these DSP algorithms, then use that OCR code and see whether or not the classification rate is better.

Comment: Thanks for you link, it's very interesting. I will study that. I heard my lecturer said about face regconize, smile recognize and I think OCR is DSP application. I think I should prepare a backup subject for this assignment. Do do have any suggestion about applying DSP to sound?

Comment: You can do **a lot**. Cleaning up audio is one app: Removing echo and reverb, going from 2 channel and artificially making surround sound, and the best thing is **sound effects**.  You ever play  with your sound equalizer in your audio player? Making your song sound like you're in a different environment (stadium, studio, and even a bar bathroom!) is a cool app. Guitar effects!: Delay, Flanger, Distortion / Overdrive.  The possibilities are endless.  Check out this awesome demo video from MathWorks to get you started: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/audio-signal-processing-in-matlab-86358.html

Answer (score 1):

Digital Signal Processing is the study of pattern processing by logical algorithmic processes.

It involves measurements, statistics, geometry, and many other easy digital tasks that you don't realize that you already know.

The patterns are often 2D graphs, 3D, Sounds, in a variety of bit depths and resolutions... 
Question: How to convert an image file into digital signals? An image file is an X,Y, graph. You mostly read through them with loops. What did you expect?

You can represent some images as vectors. You can represent writings as vectors in a PC as well, like "L" is two vectors.

99 percent of common image DSP uses vectors and rasters.

So when you talk about OCR signal processing, have a think about how a human brain can recognize the letters.

Apprentice readers first locate the line and travel forwards through the line.

The they use the space around every letter to single out individual letters.

Then they compare the letters to their memory, to recall if it is A,a, B,b, C,c.

That gives you an idea of a way for a computer to do it.

- find lines of characters. They have long horizontal spacings that are easy to see in an XY loop.
- find elements in every line which are seperated by a vertical spacer.
- compare that character using the simplest OCR science.

OCR represents only a millionth of DSP science, but OCR porbably has dozens and dozens PhD's, web tutorials and github projects for you to search in.

When you have recognized 1.2.3. steps of the process of your logic, you can compare other methods and learn from them, and then you will have read 2 pages about OCR. by the time you have scanned 10,20 or 100 pages on OCR you probably found some nicely illustrated web pages which chill you out and which make you a genius of DSP OCR.

Comment: Why did this question appear at the top of a search for "DSP" on stackoverflow???

Answer (score -1):

If you are intending to use Matlab. This is the way to do it . you read the image and find its descriptors. Each letter in the alphabet should have its own unique descriptors .

```
I=imreadbw('data/box.jpg') ;

[f,d,gss,dogss] = sift(I,'verbosity',1,'boundarypoint',0,'threshold',.0282,'firstoctave',-1,'edgethreshold',0) ;   
d = uint8(512*d) ;
```